# how to remove image code from sql file? is there any converter or tools?

Tags: mysql, oracle, base64

Actually I have an oracle database exported as sql file having a field name EMP_PIC which has unusual texts that I can not manage. I want it to import into mysql database as EMP_PIC would be null and other fields will be as it is already. Attached picture is a row of sql file, I want it to import mysql database without emp_pic data

[image]

Comment: Would probably be a good idea to censore personal data on the image (if not already done or fake data). I don't need to know she is single and born on ... and what her religion is ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use oracle to do that.

1. Import the script into oracle
2. `UPDATE table SET EMP_PIC = null;`
3. Export the table structure.

Then you have a new script but without those binary data.

Comment: thanks but I have only sql file now so I can not run a query, Its my client database I want it to import into mysql without the picture code.

Comment: I know. As I wrote to get the table back you can first import it to oracle. Then you have a table which you can update. Then export that updated table and you have a Script without binary data.

Comment: It's not a converter you asked for, but it's one alternative to workaround your problem tho.

Comment: I have only mysql database how can I import it to oracle? In that case I need to visit client. But I don't have that option now

Comment: You could download the [Oracle developer edition](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html), but that's a quite heavy weight solution tbh... I don't know a converter tool that solvices this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `expdp` for exporting you can simply provide a REMAP_DATA parameter to change the data or set it to null.

You can read more about it here: [REMAP_DATA](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-B1D13216-93D3-4FFC-A0BB-082E133FD2B9.htm#SUTIL861)